# R data.table to list of rows; better ways?

Tags: r, list, data.table

I want to convert an R data.table into a list of rows (each row being represented by a list). So far I have found two ways of doing this:

```
library(data.table)

x.dt = data.table(x = seq(1, 10), y = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), key="x")

# Using lapply & split
x.list.1 = lapply(split(x.dt, rownames(x.dt)), as.list)

# Using Lapply
x.list.2 = lapply(as.list(1:nrow(x.dt)), function(row) as.list(x.dt[row[1],]))
```

They both seem a bit clunky to me. Is there a better (more concise) way of doing this?

Kind regards,
Herman

Comment: Out of curiosity: why? This seems less than useful and generally a bad idea.

Comment: @Roland I need to export a summary of a table to nested tree structure (JSON).

Answer (score 4):

Use apply by rows:

```
x.list.3 <- apply(x.dt,1,as.list)
```

Comment: This solution has a catch: apply returns an atomic vector. Hence, the rows you get our of apply consist of elements which all have the same data type, even if there were columns of different types in your dataframe. This may not be what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that this is any less clunky, but this works:

```
as.list(as.data.table(t(x.dt)))
```

You transpose the `data.table` using `t()`, then declare it to be a `data.table` again, the make it into a `list`.

The output:

```
$V1
[1] " 1" "a" 

$V2
[1] " 2" "b" 

$V3
[1] " 3" "c" 

$V4
[1] " 4" "d" 

$V5
[1] " 5" "e" 

$V6
[1] " 6" "f" 

$V7
[1] " 7" "g" 

$V8
[1] " 8" "h" 

$V9
[1] " 9" "i" 

$V10
[1] "10" "j"
```

As @akrun noted in the comments, the output here is different from your examples, but it is still each row in a list, so you may find that better or worse.

**Edit**
As @David Arenburg pointed out in the comments,

```
as.list(unlist(t(x.dt)))
```

provides the same output as the two examples in the question.

Comment: You can reach OP's desired output with a slight change `as.list(unlist(t(x.dt)))`

Comment: This works, but I doesn't preserve the types. In the case of my example everything is coerced into strings. Same goes for @Marat Talipov's  solution.